# Use Stanford coreNlp in UIMA framework

Tags: java, serialization, stanford-nlp, uima, ducc

I have to use some of the Stanford core NLP annotators into UIMA framework to scale up the application using DUCC.

The most direct way to do this would be parsing the coreMap to cas and back again to coreMap in another annotator.

Is there any other way to do this?

Maybe through serialization.....

Answer (score 0):

I would go with dkpro implementation of stanford tools such [parser](https://dkpro.github.io/dkpro-core/java/recipes/stanfordnlp/#stanfordparser)
. If there is missing features there, implement them and provide them back to the community.